# Coffeescript: replace an <img> src attribute

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am new to coffee script and my end goal is to change the value of src in image tag to a different one. 
 the input will be a string.

lets say

```
string  x = '<div class="sample">
                 <img src="/i/java.png"> 
             </div>
             <div class="sample">
                 <img src="/i/python.png"> 
            </div>'
```

I want to replace the contents of src to something else.
I tried with the regex to try it out but it does not work. 
Any idea on how do i achieve this. I used this regex.

```
 s.replace /[/"][//]{1}i[//]{1}/g, '"//cdn.example.com/'
```

i am using my local application as well as [this](https://www.jdoodle.com/compile-coffeescript-online) website to test my code

Comment: If you were to create these elements via the DOM API, you could just change the `.src` property without any regular expressions. Is there a particular reason you are using strings of HTML?

Comment: ohh no I am not changing the DOM element. this string would be used as a dynamic content for other domain :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a problem with your original regex.

Give this example a try,

```
x = '<div class="sample">
             <img src="/i/java.png"> 
         </div>
         <div class="sample">
             <img src="/i/python.png"> 
        </div>'

console.log(x.replace /\/i\/[a-zA-Z1-9]+.png/g, '"//cdn.example.com/')
```

The regex `/\/i\/[a-zA-Z1-9]+.png/g` should match any values with the format of `/i/anything_here.png`, but ensures that the `anything_here` value contains at least 1 character (so `/i/.png` won't match).

---

If your string might contain more subpaths before the `.png` filename, use the following regex - `\/i(\/[a-zA-Z1-9]+)+.png`

This regex will allow as many occurrences of `/anything` before the `/filename.png`.

Comment: so i might also have somethings like `/i/some/other/dir/xyz.png`  any idea how to deal with that ?   i would just want to add //cdn.example.com in the front if there is none

Comment: x.replace /\"\/i\//g, '"//cdn.example.com/i/'  
This gives me the right option this shluld work as well ?

Comment: That regex is not working for me; but if it is, feel free!

Comment: Your idea helped me. i didnt knew /xx/g worked in coffeescript as well. thanks alot :)